# Sample Frequency - Recommended Practical Nyquist, Lower Used by majorities appications

Tags: frequency, sampling, nyquist

**Doubt1:** What is the Lowest Sampling Frequency used by majorities sound applications. Is there limited frequency sampling lower than 8KHz In C/C++?

**Comment** In Java I haven't detected any problem, but using VCL program into one wav sound file (with lower Freq to 8K) was not played, producing Error!

**Doubt2:** Can I to capture sound using arbitrary Frequency Sampling in C/C++? This process/function/method depends on specific Library? Can I to do this using pure C/C++ Code (without specialized Libraries), where?

Maybe this is a foolish question. I have sound with the 100Hz-500Hz Spectrum.

**Doubt3:** What is the recommended lowest Nyquist Sampling Frequency (I Know that teorical is two), but is there another practical Criterion? Example: Is recommended to use 2.5, 3 or 4.
In my sound the TEORICAL Nyquist sampling Frequency must be 1KHz.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

44.1 kHz and 48 kHz are sampling frequencies that are almost always supported by software and drivers but if you need to go lower than that then stop at 8 kHz, as it is commonly supported.